# Broken repos by applying git clone and add . to a parent folder

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-clone, git-add

This is the 2nd time it happens to me. The first time I thought it was a hard drive problem.

I'm trying to back up all my projects, that don't have a Repos in it. Because of my bad practices, I've local projects with repo and local projects without it. All projects are in a folder named `Workspace`.

I tried to backup everything creating a new repo in GitHub, I did a clone and then copy all the files ( in this case two files `Readme.md` and the folder `.git`) on the `Workspace` Folder. Then I apply

```
git add . 
git commit -m "backing up"
```

After some time, I receive an error, talking of submodules, etc. I realize that I should do other things applying submodules and git. In any case, I change the strategy to back up my local projects.

The problem is, that all my local projects that have repos, git don't recognize the repos. git doesn't "see" the repos. I believe those commands change something on those inner projects.
Each project has its own `.git` folder but it doesn't matter. Git doesn't see the repo.
I've been trying to find a solution for two days now, and I didn't format my pc yet just in case
:( .
I believe that is something related to the files inside `.git` folder, `HEAD` file is not in the `.git` folder, it doesn't exist. Thank you

Comment: Git *cannot* store a Git repository. This is administratively forbidden *by* Git for security reasons. If you somehow create a Git repository that contains a sub-repository, other Git commands on other systems will refuse to *use* that repository. If you do try to add a repository that's contained inside another repository's working tree, Git won't add the *repository itself*, but rather a *reference to the other repository*. This won't work as a backup solution. Git isn't intended to be a backup system either, though: for doing backups, consider a real backup system.

Comment: (Note that very old versions of Git accidentally let you store a sub-repository within a repository, using naming tricks. If you clone one of these with a modern Git, it won't use it.)

Comment: I know is not the best tool for backup, but that's not the point of the question. The point of the question is that I've broken repos and I would like to fix it. In any case, thank you for giving me your time for the previous explanation.

Comment: Well ... one typical way a Git clone gets corrupted is if you clone into a cloud-synced repository. The cloud-syncing software thinks these are human-driven files and "resolves" problems by, e.g., renaming `HEAD` to `HEAD 1` and `HEAD 2` and so on. You mention missing `HEAD` files (and those do cause Git to believe that Git repository is no longer a Git repository) so investigating what made that happen—cloud-sync is just one possibility—would be a good idea.